# How do I match rows in one pandas dataframe to the rows in another dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

everyone. I have run into a problem in attempting to match rows in one dataframe to another dataframe using the Python Pandas library.

I have two dataframes, df_1 and df_2, that have three of the exact same columns: A "Date", "Location", and "Data" column. The Location values in *df_1* are correct, however, in *df_2*, some location values are not. To summarize, what I am trying to do is keep all three columns and their respective values in each for *df_2* except those rows whose values in the "Location" column do NOT match those values in the "Location" column of *df_1*.

It looks like this:

```
df_1:
Date        Location        Data
1/1/2000    12345670        57.573
1/1/2000    12345671        67.374
1/1/2000    12345672        56.926
1/1/2000    12345673        62.492
1/1/2000    12345674        65.735
1/2/2000    12345670        56.684
1/2/2000    12345671        58.243
1/2/2000    12345672        60.305
1/2/2000    12345673        61.294


df_2:
Date        Location        Data
1/1/2000    12345670        64.684
1/1/2000    12345671        55.574
1/1/2000    12345672        53.983
1/1/2000    12345673        63.103
1/1/2000    12345674        69.485
1/1/2000    EUF57324        57.682
1/1/2000    ARIF6872        56.773
1/1/2000    GHUEF398        65.126
1/2/2000    12345670        62.503
1/2/2000    12345671        60.604
1/2/2000    MAR40521        54.468
1/2/2000    WOP68494        67.295
```

As you can see, there are some values within the "Location" column of *df_2* that do not have the same numerical characteristics as are in *df_1*. The other values in the "Location" column of *df_2* overlap with the "Location" column of *df_1*. I just want to match the rows in the "Date" and "Location" columns of *df_2* to those in the "Location" and "Date" columns of *df_1* so that the odd location values in *df_2* are omitted. I do not need the "*Data*" column in *df_1*, just the "Date" and "Location" columns to match.

I want the matched dataframe to look like this:

```
Matched_df_2:
Date        Location        Data
1/1/2000    12345670        64.684
1/1/2000    12345671        55.574
1/1/2000    12345672        53.983
1/1/2000    12345673        63.103
1/1/2000    12345674        69.485
1/2/2000    12345670        62.503
1/2/2000    12345671        60.604
```

The odd location values will have disappeared.

I have attempted to use the "merge" function in pandas to do the join, but it keeps giving me an empty dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv')
df_1 = df_1.astype({'Location': 'object'}) #conversion of datatype to "object" from int64 

print(df_1)
print(df_2)

df_merge = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['Date', 'Location'])

print(df_merge)

#It returns an empty dataframe, as shown below 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Location, df_1_data, df_2_data]
Index: []
```

I assume I am just missing something in how I am doing the merge. In SQL, this would be straightforward using an INNER JOIN or matching WHERE statement to match the rows in the "Date" and "Location" of *data_table_2* to those in *data_table_1*.

I hope what I wrote here makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that you only want the values in df_2 where there is a corresponding match of the location in df_1?  And further that the locations in df_1 that don't have a match in df_2 either don't exist or can be ignored?

Comment: @JeffH, to your first question, yes, that is accurate. For your second part, if a location value in df_2 does not match with a location value in df_1, I want it to be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this line:

```
df1 = df1.astype({'Location': 'object'})
```

You want to cast them into `str` instead:

```
df1 = df1.astype({'Location': 'str'})

df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Location'])

print(df_merge)

       Date  Location  Data_x  Data_y
0  1/1/2000  12345670  57.573  64.684
1  1/1/2000  12345671  67.374  55.574
2  1/1/2000  12345672  56.926  53.983
3  1/1/2000  12345673  62.492  63.103
4  1/1/2000  12345674  65.735  69.485
5  1/2/2000  12345670  56.684  62.503
6  1/2/2000  12345671  58.243  60.604
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert the variable "Location" in df1 into string as the variable "Location" in the df2 is in string. You can use the below code:

```
df1['Location'] = df1['Location'].astype(str)
df1.dtypes
df2.dtypes
match = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['Date', 'Location'])
print(match)

       Date  Location  Data_x  Data_y
0  1/1/2000  12345670  57.573  64.684
1  1/1/2000  12345671  67.374  55.574
2  1/1/2000  12345672  56.926  53.983
3  1/1/2000  12345673  62.492  63.103
4  1/1/2000  12345674  65.735  69.485
5  1/2/2000  12345670  56.684  62.503
6  1/2/2000  12345671  58.243  60.604
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "isin()" method:

```
crit= df2.Location.astype(str).isin(df1.Location.astype(str))                                                        
df2= df2.loc[crit]
```